# "Telerik" could not be found in global namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, telerik

Currently I am working on a ASP.NET web form project which is using Telerik Ajax Version 2015.2.623.45, I have added **Telerik.Web.UI.dll**, **Telerik.Web.Design.dll** into my project reference, but it keeps giving me errors saying

`The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Here's some info of my project if that may helps:

I am using .NET Framework 4, using Integrated Mode,

the `dll`'s `Aliases` property is "global", and `Copy Local` property is True

and my `web.config` contains following parts:

```js
<controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
</controls>
        ...
        ...
<httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResourceSession, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
        ...
        ...
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI.RadTextBox, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.2.623.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
          <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.2.623.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
          <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxManagerProxy, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.2.623.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
          <add assembly="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCodeBlock, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.2.623.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
            ...
            ...
        </assemblies>
</compilation>
          
         ...
         ...
         
<handlers>
          <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
          <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResourceSession, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
```

I have Googled a lot and tried all method on Telerik Forum, but it does not help...Can someone help me and tell me what am I missing, and how can I reference `Telerik.*.dll` correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the references and adding them again. In the properties of the references, "Copy Local" should be set to true (but I think this is the default). Also, make sure you're adding them to the correct project in your solution! (This tripped me up once.)

Finally, make sure the DLLs you are referencing are built against the same version of the .NET Framework your project is targeting. If they're not, you'll get something like the following warning when building:

`Warning    1576    The primary reference "Telerik.Web.Design, Version=2014.2.724.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simply add the missing the references, this might give you an indication of missing dll files [missing dlls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpLX7.png). Your telerik dlls should be under C:\ Programe Files(x86)\Progress

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the Telerik ASP.NET AJAX VS Extensions. To convert your project using the Telerik ASP.NET AJAX VS Extensions follow these steps:
Select your web site project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.
In the Visual Studio menu select Telerik -> UI for ASP.NET AJAX -> Convert to Telerik Web Site
Use the configuration wizard to convert your web site. You can find more information about Configure wizard options in our documentation at http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/integration-with-visual-studio/visual-studio-extensions/creation-and-configuration-wizard.
If you still prefer to manually manage the Telerik resources in you project you can take a look at http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/adding-the-telerik-controls-to-your-project.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your target Framework of your current project 
then check your assembly version of telerik control in 2 part : one in toolbox panel and the other one in  project reference section,
all of them must be the same.

for detail of version assembly and Framework check out the link :

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/installation/included-assemblies